# Deny loading of php files if accessed directly (nginx)

Tags: php, security, nginx

I don't know if this can be achieved... I'll try anyway.
I'd like to deny php files in a certain folder to be viewable if loaded directly (you point the browser to the direct URL), but only if you clicked on a link pointing to them on a certain page.
Can this be achieved in nginx with a location..? It's nothing security involved, so if the method isn't 100% secure it's not a problem..

EDIT: Ok, let's add some details.. I have a VPS and I have a page with a login box. After you enter the login details you access to a page with links to phpinfo/phpsysinfo/webmin panel/apc status/nginx status. So a page where you have links to software to monitor stats of my VPS. I know that security through obscurity isn't ok but I feel more confortable to have those info not really exposed. So I'd like to deny access to those pages (all in 1 directory) denying direct access (but only if you come from the page protected by login box).

Comment: It would help a bit if you could be more specific as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why not simply do HTTP-based basic authentication?  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is based on the `HTTP_REFERER` header. If you could do this with Nginx, you'd have to do it with an if block, which would be inefficient. I'm not sure you could do it any other way. But you shouldn't be doing this anyway as, as you said, it isn't really secure, just hidden.

You should look at these:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthDigestModule

Digest would be more secure. Basic transmits user/password in the clear. But either would be far more secure than what you're describing as the pages are actually protected.

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this as soon as I can! Will accept the answer that works. :)

Comment: Ok, the HttpAuthBasicModule seems to work.. the problem is that after I insert the credentials instead of displaying the php files protected by the httpauth module the browser downloads the file.. there seems to be a problem with MIME. This is the interesting portion I have in nginx vhost:
http://pastebin.com/PsEv79sv

Comment: I think you need a `try_files` in your `location ^~ /stats/` after the auth lines.

Comment: Uhm.. added try_files $uri $uri/ index.php; with no luck.. :(

Comment: Any hint..? Fixed this problem everything works! :)

Comment: Solution found. :)
I combined /stats/ location with php location: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11167338/1342772

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Nested location block works good for static and .php files. Your "location /" block threw me off because it looked like you wanted to send all requests to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Looking here might be what you're after: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule

The following would redirect all direct requests to the 403 forbidden page.

```
error_page  403  http://example.com/forbidden.html;
location / {
  deny    all;
}
```

Of course you can still access that code from your another PHP script if you wish, it just prevents external direct access.

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this as soon as I can! Will accept the answer that works. :)